# CSS transition when parent class changes?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm using a CSS parent class to define multiple layouts for some data.  When I change the parent class, the layout changes perfectly as desired, however I thought it may be fun to add some CSS animations (transitions).  I can't seem to get it to work though.  I found one other similar question, but it has no answer, and it's not exactly the same (or as straightforward).

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/wmK2F/1/

I don't really care *what* transitions right now; height, width, color, whatever.  Once someone shows me what I'm doing wrong I can tweak it.

HTML:

```
<div id="toggleLayout">Click To Toggle</div>
<div class="layout layoutCards">
    <span class="entity">
        Test
    </span>
    <span class="entity">
        Test
    </span>    
    <span class="entity">
        Test
    </span>    
    <span class="entity">
        Test
    </span>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.entity { /* animate */
  -webkit-transition: height .5s linear;
  -moz-transition: height .5s linear;
}

.layoutCards .entity {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.layoutList .entity {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You can’t change the `display` value from `inline-block` to `block` at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the `display` of the element from `inline-block` to `block`. You cannot transition such a change. You could easily just make the `display` of both the same; however, that eliminates the desired behavior.

As opposed to manipulating the elements via the `display` property, you could swap `display:inline-block` out for `float:left`, set `float:none`, on the second element, and keep `display:block`. This seems to work. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FGW4t/), but it doesn't produce a nice animation due to the radical changes..

```
.layoutCards .entity {
    float: left;
}

.layoutList .entity {
    float: none;
    display:block;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also just set `display:block` on both. Producing this - [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgqqJ/).

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  This just isn't going to work.  Too bad, I love the feature but the transition is a bit jarring.  Thanks for the explanation and alternative examples.